# How to insert a multiline data tupple in orientdb

Tags: orientdb

I need to insert a data in an orientdb class but it has multiple lines and it is not accepted during insertion.

Say there is a column in a sql table which has a data like this.

"Hi There! /NewLine/
I am Blah! /NewLine/
I am lost!"

How to insert a data like that in orientdb cmd prompt console?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look at the [ask] page and improve your question: what have you tried so far/what is not working? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your question wasn't clear but this is one of the different ways to insert multiple records:

```
insert into User(name,lastName,address) values ("Jon","Doe","9633 W Olympic Blvd"),("Jane","Doe","315-353 S Beverly Dr")
```

I have a User class with 3 properties: name, lastName and address

this is the output of the above command:

[image]

Hope it helps

Regards